# show that $F$ is a $\sigma-$field

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f$ be a non-empty collection of subsets of $C$

Define $F = ∩\{G; f ⊂ G,$ where $G$ is a $\sigma-$field }.
Show that $F$ is a $\sigma-$field.
($F$ is the smallest $\sigma-$field which contains $f$ and is referred to as the $\sigma-$field generated
by $f$.)

How can I show that $F$ is a $\sigma-$field ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please edit the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: A $\sigma$-field or $\sigma$-algebra has three properties (contains universal set - presumably $C$ here, closed under complementation, closed under countable unions).  You need to show $F$ satisfies each of these properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $X$ is a set then $\mathcal{S}$, set of subsets of $X$, is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$ if it satisfies the three properties:

(1) $\emptyset\in \mathcal{S}$;

(2) $E\in \mathcal{S}\Rightarrow (X\setminus E)\in \mathcal{S}$;

(3) $E_1,E_2,\dots\in\mathcal{S}\Rightarrow \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k\in \mathcal{S}$

---

(1) $\emptyset\in G$ in $F$ since every $G$ is a $\sigma$-algebra so $\emptyset$ belongs to the intersection of all sigma-algebras i.e. $\emptyset \in F$.

(2) Now suppose that a set $E\in F$: then $E\in G$ for every $G\in F$ and since the $G$s are $\sigma$-algebras $E^c \in G$ for every $G$ in $F$ thus $E^c$ belongs to their intersection, i.e. $E^c \in F$.

(3) Let $E_1, E_2,\dots \in F$: then $E_1,E_2,\dots \in G$ for every $G$ in $F$ so $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k\in G$ for every $G$ in $F$ thus $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k \in F$, and this concludes the proof.